# Is there any shortcut to collapse all open panes and focus on the open file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking to find a shortcut that will help me collapse all the open panes(search, terminal) and focus only on the opened file so i can see the file in full screen.
[image]

I know there are shortcuts to close each pane individually. Zen mode is not helping me as it just opens the file, but it is not full screen. It kind looks lost in space..

I am expecting something like this, from the initial state picture I have added.
[image]

Note that the keyboard shortcut for explorer, debug panes are different from search pane. I am looking for a single shortcut to see the complete view of the opened file.

thanks

Comment: The question is such that I have no clue what you want to do. Which `Open Panes`? Have you tried `View | Appearance | Full Screen`

Comment: @rioV8 yes, infact the first screenshot is in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `View: Toggle zen mode`. The default shortcut is `cmd + K Z`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is `Close Panel` and `Close Side Bar`.

You can use the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).

In `settings.json`:

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.sideBarClosePanelClose",
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.action.closeSidebar",
        "workbench.action.closePanel"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

In `keybindings.json`:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+z",  // or any other key combo
    "command": "multiCommand.sideBarClosePanelClose"
  }
```